# Better ways to create various kind of View Controllers on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, scripting, uiviewcontroller, performance

The thing is this: when we program for an iPhone app, we can add some more classes for those view controllers and such. But honestly, debugging and compiling these kind of programs get old real fast. Sure, we have the iPhone simulator, but sometimes, you just have to change some tiny things and you have to compile again. This is tedious.

On a desktop program, some applications, for instance, games. They have scripts to control the logic of the game. If the programmers have to change something in the game, they can simply change the script, save the script, request the game to reload the script. There, this is much better. Development is more rapid, although the program does not run at native speed. This is just one possible example of what I would like to have with iPhone development.

Note that the iPhone apps in this case, I am referring to general apps. Apps that require Tab View Controller, Table View Controller, etc., the normal iPhone UI app, in other words.

I have also seen an API claiming that they can use HTML-like language to create iPhone UI, but I never tried it out though. There is also a question of performance in my mind as well, but I think iPhone should be able to handle the performance.

So I am looking for a faster and more efficient way to create an iPhone app *legally*. Beside the ordinary way, are there other more efficient ways?

Comment: You basically have 2 options: 1) you make a change to a class, you recompile, you can't avoid it 2) you use your iphone app as an html wrapper and you write an html5 app